# returning html tags from ajax request c#

Tags: c#, html, ajax

I am able to display HTML elements when retrieving data from a database. When retrieving data via an ajax request however, it seems the HTML elements are ignored. I'd like to retrieve HTML elements using the ajax request. Any help here would be appreciated.

```
private class loadvals
{
    public string html { get; set; }
}


[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetHtml(int id)
{
    connection conn = new connection();

    string query = "Select html from table where id = '1'";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conn.GetConnectionString()))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            List<loadvals> cus = new List<loadvals>();
            loadvals row;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    row = new loadvals();
                    row.post = System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(sdr["html"].ToString());
                    cus.Add(row);
                }
            }
            con.Close();
            var ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var serialized = ser.Serialize(cus);
            return serialized;
        }
    }
} 



function javascriptFunction(test) {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: "/html.aspx/GetHtml",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (r) {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(r.d);
        for (var i = 0; i < parsed.length; i++) {
            alert(parsed[i]["html"]);
        }
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(XMLHttpRequest + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});
return false;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: use the AllowHtml attribute which you would apply to a property on your model class.

class loadvals
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string html { get; set; }
}

Comment: I am not using the mvc framework for this

Answer (score 0):

Change ajax property 'dataType: "json"' to 'dataType: "html"'

Comment: I changed the dataType property to html but that didnt work also, the page just gets reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
1.Change the datatype to html 
2.Remove the Content type from Ajax request.(No data you are sending for request.)
```

**contentType** When sending data to the server, use this content type.

**dataType** The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response

Refer documentation. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: "/html.aspx/GetHtml",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (r) {
       .....
        }
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(XMLHttpRequest + " " + textStatus + " " + errorThrown);
    }
});
return false;
}
```